# sudo lshw shows UNCLAIMED for memory, serial, Intel and AMD Radeon graphics

Tags: drivers

```
description: Notebook
    product: Vostro 3578 (0844)
    vendor: Dell Inc.
    serial: G436WN2
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-3.1 dmi-3.1 smp vsyscall32
    configuration: boot=normal chassis=notebook family=Vostro sku=0844 uuid=44454C4C-3400-1033-8036-C7C04F574E32
*-core
    description: Motherboard
    product: 01Y7V4
    vendor: Dell Inc.
    physical id: 0
    version: A00
    serial: /G436WN2/CNWSC00877000X/
    *-firmware
        description: BIOS
        vendor: Dell Inc.
        physical id: 0
        version: 1.3.0
        date: 03/01/2018
        size: 64KiB
        capacity: 15MiB
        capabilities: pci pnp upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int13floppynec int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb smartbattery biosbootspecification netboot uefi
    *-memory
        description: System Memory
        physical id: 3d
        slot: System board or motherboard
        size: 4GiB
        *-bank:0
            description: SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2400 MHz (0.4 ns)
            product: M471A5244BB0-CRC
            vendor: Samsung
            physical id: 0
            serial: 123221DD
            slot: DIMM A
            size: 4GiB
            width: 64 bits
            clock: 2400MHz (0.4ns)
        *-bank:1
            description: [empty]
            physical id: 1
            slot: ChannelB-DIMM0
    *-cache:0
        description: L1 cache
        physical id: 41
        slot: L1 Cache
        size: 256KiB
        capacity: 256KiB
        capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
        configuration: level=1
    *-cache:1
        description: L2 cache
        physical id: 42
        slot: L2 Cache
        size: 1MiB
        capacity: 1MiB
        capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
        configuration: level=2
    *-cache:2
        description: L3 cache
        physical id: 43
        slot: L3 Cache
        size: 6MiB
        capacity: 6MiB
        capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
        configuration: level=3
    *-cpu
        description: CPU
        product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8250U CPU @ 1.60GHz
        vendor: Intel Corp.
        physical id: 44
        bus info: cpu@0
        version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8250U CPU @ 1.60GHz
        serial: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
        slot: U3E1
        size: 800MHz
        capacity: 3400MHz
        width: 64 bits
        clock: 100MHz
        capabilities: x86-64 fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault epb invpcid_single pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid ept_ad fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid mpx rdseed adx smap clflushopt intel_pt xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_notify hwp_act_window hwp_epp md_clear flush_l1d cpufreq
        configuration: cores=4 enabledcores=4 threads=8
    *-pci
        description: Host bridge
        product: Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers
        vendor: Intel Corporation
        physical id: 100
        bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
        version: 08
        width: 32 bits
        clock: 33MHz
        configuration: driver=skl_uncore
        resources: irq:0
        *-display UNCLAIMED
            description: VGA compatible controller
            product: UHD Graphics 620
            vendor: Intel Corporation
            physical id: 2
            bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
            version: 07
            width: 64 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
            configuration: latency=0
            resources: memory:d1000000-d1ffffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
        *-generic:0
            description: Signal processing controller
            product: Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem
            vendor: Intel Corporation
            physical id: 4
            bus info: pci@0000:00:04.0
            version: 08
            width: 64 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: msi pm cap_list
            configuration: driver=proc_thermal latency=0
            resources: irq:16 memory:d2320000-d2327fff
        *-usb
            description: USB controller
            product: Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
            vendor: Intel Corporation
            physical id: 14
            bus info: pci@0000:00:14.0
            version: 21
            width: 64 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: pm msi xhci bus_master cap_list
            configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
            resources: irq:125 memory:d2310000-d231ffff
        *-usbhost:0
                product: xHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 5.3.0-40-generic xhci-hcd
                physical id: 0
                bus info: usb@1
                logical name: usb1
                version: 5.03
                capabilities: usb-2.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=12 speed=480Mbit/s
            *-usb:0
                description: Video
                product: Integrated_Webcam_HD
                vendor: CN0F08KGLOG00858B1BHA02
                physical id: 5
                bus info: usb@1:5
                version: 65.05
                capabilities: usb-2.00
                configuration: driver=uvcvideo maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
            *-usb:1
                description: Generic USB device
                product: USB2.0-CRW
                vendor: Generic
                physical id: 6
                bus info: usb@1:6
                version: 39.60
                serial: 20100201396000000
                capabilities: usb-2.00
                configuration: driver=rtsx_usb maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
            *-usb:2
                description: Bluetooth wireless interface
                vendor: Atheros Communications, Inc.
                physical id: 7
                bus info: usb@1:7
                version: 0.01
                capabilities: bluetooth usb-2.01
                configuration: driver=btusb maxpower=100mA speed=12Mbit/s
            *-usb:3 UNCLAIMED
                description: Generic USB device
                vendor: Validity Sensors, Inc.
                physical id: 9
                bus info: usb@1:9
                version: 1.64
                serial: 56bbb807853c
                capabilities: usb-2.00
                configuration: maxpower=100mA speed=12Mbit/s
        *-usbhost:1
                product: xHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 5.3.0-40-generic xhci-hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@2
                logical name: usb2
                version: 5.03
                capabilities: usb-3.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=6 speed=5000Mbit/s
        *-generic:1
            description: Signal processing controller
            product: Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem
            vendor: Intel Corporation
            physical id: 14.2
            bus info: pci@0000:00:14.2
            version: 21
            width: 64 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: pm msi cap_list
            configuration: driver=intel_pch_thermal latency=0
            resources: irq:18 memory:d2337000-d2337fff
        *-generic:2
            description: Signal processing controller
            product: Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0
            vendor: Intel Corporation
            physical id: 15
            bus info: pci@0000:00:15.0
            version: 21
            width: 64 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
            configuration: driver=intel-lpss latency=0
            resources: irq:16 memory:d2336000-d2336fff
        *-communication
            description: Communication controller
            product: Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1
            vendor: Intel Corporation
            physical id: 16
            bus info: pci@0000:00:16.0
            version: 21
            width: 64 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
            configuration: driver=mei_me latency=0
            resources: irq:128 memory:d2335000-d2335fff
        *-storage
            description: SATA controller
            product: Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
            vendor: Intel Corporation
            physical id: 17
            bus info: pci@0000:00:17.0
            version: 21
            width: 32 bits
            clock: 66MHz
            capabilities: storage msi pm ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list
            configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
            resources: irq:126 memory:d2330000-d2331fff memory:d2334000-d23340ff ioport:f090(size=8) ioport:f080(size=4) ioport:f060(size=32) memory:d2333000-d23337ff
        *-pci:0
            description: PCI bridge
            product: Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1
            vendor: Intel Corporation
            physical id: 1c
            bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.0
            version: f1
            width: 32 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
            configuration: driver=pcieport
            resources: irq:122 ioport:e000(size=4096) memory:c0000000-d00fffff
        *-display UNCLAIMED
                description: Display controller
                product: Jet PRO [Radeon R5 M230]
                vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
                version: c3
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm pciexpress msi cap_list
                configuration: latency=0
                resources: memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d003ffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:d0040000-d005ffff
        *-pci:1
            description: PCI bridge
            product: Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5
            vendor: Intel Corporation
            physical id: 1c.4
            bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.4
            version: f1
            width: 32 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
            configuration: driver=pcieport
            resources: irq:123 ioport:d000(size=4096) memory:d2200000-d22fffff
        *-network
                description: Ethernet interface
                product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
                vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
                logical name: enp2s0
                version: 15
                serial: 54:48:10:c5:0d:c3
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical
                configuration: broadcast=yes driver=r8169 latency=0 multicast=yes
                resources: irq:16 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:d2204000-d2204fff memory:d2200000-d2203fff
        *-pci:2
            description: PCI bridge
            product: Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #6
            vendor: Intel Corporation
            physical id: 1c.5
            bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.5
            version: f1
            width: 32 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
            configuration: driver=pcieport
            resources: irq:124 memory:d2000000-d21fffff
        *-network
                description: Wireless interface
                product: QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
                vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
                logical name: wlp3s0
                version: 31
                serial: 74:40:bb:7f:2a:7b
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
                configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=5.3.0-40-generic firmware=WLAN.TF.2.1-00021-QCARMSWP-1 ip=172.16.1.18 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
                resources: irq:129 memory:d2000000-d21fffff
        *-isa
            description: ISA bridge
            product: Intel(R) 100 Series Chipset Family LPC Controller/eSPI Controller - 9D4E
            vendor: Intel Corporation
            physical id: 1f
            bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.0
            version: 21
            width: 32 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: isa bus_master
            configuration: latency=0
        *-memory UNCLAIMED
            description: Memory controller
            product: Sunrise Point-LP PMC
            vendor: Intel Corporation
            physical id: 1f.2
            bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
            version: 21
            width: 32 bits
            clock: 33MHz (30.3ns)
            configuration: latency=0
            resources: memory:d232c000-d232ffff
        *-multimedia
            description: Audio device
            product: Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio
            vendor: Intel Corporation
            physical id: 1f.3
            bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
            version: 21
            width: 64 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
            configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=32
            resources: irq:130 memory:d2328000-d232bfff memory:d2300000-d230ffff
        *-serial UNCLAIMED
            description: SMBus
            product: Sunrise Point-LP SMBus
            vendor: Intel Corporation
            physical id: 1f.4
            bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.4
            version: 21
            width: 64 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            configuration: latency=0
            resources: memory:d2332000-d23320ff ioport:f040(size=32)
    *-scsi:0
        physical id: 1
        logical name: scsi0
        capabilities: emulated
        *-disk
            description: ATA Disk
            product: ST1000LM035-1RK1
            vendor: Seagate
            physical id: 0.0.0
            bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
            logical name: /dev/sda
            version: SDM2
            serial: ZDEAWZ72
            size: 931GiB (1TB)
            capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
            configuration: ansiversion=5 guid=e2818073-4a40-4a64-9993-fe15a11b9b9e logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=4096
        *-volume:0 UNCLAIMED
                description: Windows FAT volume
                vendor: MSDOS5.0
                physical id: 1
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,1
                version: FAT32
                serial: d800-d8dc
                size: 746MiB
                capacity: 749MiB
                capabilities: boot fat initialized
                configuration: FATs=2 filesystem=fat label=ESP name=EFI system partition
        *-volume:1
                description: Windows FAT volume
                vendor: MSDOS5.0
                physical id: 2
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,2
                logical name: /dev/sda2
                version: FAT32
                serial: 945d-8041
                size: 5102MiB
                capacity: 5119MiB
                capabilities: fat initialized
                configuration: FATs=2 filesystem=fat label=OS name=Basic data partition
        *-volume:2
                description: EXT4 volume
                vendor: Linux
                physical id: 3
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,3
                logical name: /dev/sda3
                logical name: /
                version: 1.0
                serial: cde4f312-f9ed-4b1a-97bb-e2f079354fa2
                size: 918GiB
                capabilities: journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink recover extents ext4 ext2 initialized
                configuration: created=2018-07-07 16:47:02 filesystem=ext4 label=UBUNTU lastmountpoint=/ modified=2020-02-28 15:26:06 mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro mounted=2020-02-28 15:26:16 state=mounted
        *-volume:3
                description: Linux swap volume
                vendor: Linux
                physical id: 4
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,4
                logical name: /dev/sda4
                version: 1
                serial: bc4d0c02-77bd-4283-9b25-38eebc54fa9c
                size: 7919MiB
                capacity: 7920MiB
                capabilities: nofs swap initialized
                configuration: filesystem=swap pagesize=4095
    *-scsi:1
        physical id: 2
        logical name: scsi1
        capabilities: emulated
        *-cdrom
            description: DVD-RAM writer
            product: DVD+-RW GU90N
            vendor: HL-DT-ST
            physical id: 0.0.0
            bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
            logical name: /dev/cdrom
            logical name: /dev/cdrw
            logical name: /dev/dvd
            logical name: /dev/dvdrw
            logical name: /dev/sr0
            version: A1C3
            capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
            configuration: ansiversion=5 status=nodisc
*-battery
    product: DELL GR43747
    vendor: SMP
    physical id: 1
    version: 05/30/2018
    serial: 00D6
    slot: Sys. Battery Bay
    capacity: 41440mWh
    configuration: voltage=14.8V
```

Comment: So what are the problem / question .. does something not work ?

Comment: Yes the screen brightness and resolution cannot be adjusted

Comment: sudo lshw | grep --color -i 'unclaimed'
        *-display UNCLAIMED
              *-usb:3 UNCLAIMED
           *-display UNCLAIMED
        *-memory UNCLAIMED
        *-serial UNCLAIMED
           *-volume:0 UNCLAIMED